# Create a SQL Server login for every user

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, authentication

I have a Windows application project that uses SQL Server 2012 for maintaining it's data.

For securing my app, I decided to create a SQL Server login for every user in my system.

Is this a good idea?

Comment: Advantages: VERY granular permissions. Disadvantages: Very hard to maintain, manage - it's not worth it. Alternative: Create a Windows NT Group and add people to that if you want to authenticate them directly against the database. Ideal, each group should represent a role in your application and be given the appropriate rights.

Comment: Sounds like a maintenance nightmare to me. Can't you use integrated security?

Comment: If you don't want to use integrated security (the pre-existing Windows credentials), then I would recommend to create one or multiple Windows **groups** (to which you can add users) and create logins for those groups. You could have (a) normal users, (b) more priviledged users, (c) admins or whatever grouping makes sense - but you would only have to manage two, three, five **group logins** - not one per user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try creating an access matrix table to map data access levels to each user. Then, you can show/hide the data loaded in your application depending on the access level of the signed-in user. As @dash said, this will be harder to maintain but it may well be an easier option than creating individual logins. Secondly, I suppose it would also be easier to create an insert/update/delete script to edit the matrix rather than have a DBA edit the SQL Server logins.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using `Windows Authentication` then this will be your best bet.  You could also place Users into `Roles` and specify permissions for that User group.

If you require that each user has different permissions and you you need to be precise as to which user has what permissions to each database entity (table, view, stored procedure, function etc) then creating a new user will be the way to go.  This will allow to you fine tune each account,enable/disable accounts, grant/revoke permissions easily.

As @dash states it will be harder to maintain, but I think having the granular level of security outweighs maintaining a large number base.